# Caching css, js, txt files parsed by php

Tags: php, parsing, caching, .htaccess, http-headers

### Question

I am running a bit of an experiment and could use some help.
I have created 2 files. **main-real.css** which is a standard plain ol' css file, and **main.css** which is parsed by PHP and has an `include()` which grabs the former real css file.
Here is the code for **main.css**:

```
<?php 
include("main-real.css");
?>
```

I am then adding an instruction to my **.htaccess** file to parse this css file with PHP:

```
<FilesMatch "main.css">
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .css
Header Set Content-Type "text/css"
</FilesMatch>
```

This works perfectly on my PHP 5.2 server running Apache.
The issue is that this file does not appear to be cached by the browser, or at least does not return a
`304 Not Modified` Status code like the regular un-PHP-parsed CSS file.

Here are the headers for **main-real.css** if accessed directly:

```
RESPONSE HEADERS
    Date..............Thu, 18 Nov 2010 22:10:57 GMT
    Server............Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8i DAV/2 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
    Last-Modified.....Thu, 18 Nov 2010 22:10:23 GMT
    Etag.............."11b010a-26-4955b0e6671c0"
    Accept-Ranges.....bytes
    Content-Length....38
    Content-Type......text/css

REQUEST HEADERS
    Accept.............text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Language....en-us,en;q=0.5
    Accept-Encoding....gzip,deflate
    Accept-Charset.....ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
    Keep-Alive.........115
    Connection.........keep-alive
    Cookie.............fc=fcVal=7625790752294348480
    If-Modified-Since..Thu, 18 Nov 2010 22:10:23 GMT
    If-None-Match......"11b010a-26-4955b0e6671c0"
    Cache-Control......max-age=0
```

Here are the headers for the PHP parsed **main.css**:

```
RESPONSE HEADERS
    Date...............Thu, 18 Nov 2010 22:11:11 GMT
    Server.............Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8i DAV/2 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
    X-Powered-By.......PHP/5.2.11
    Content-Type.......text/css
    Keep-Alive.........timeout=5, max=97
    Connection.........Keep-Alive
    Transfer-Encoding..chunked

REQUEST HEADERS
    Accept.............text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Language....en-us,en;q=0.5
    Accept-Encoding....gzip,deflate
    Accept-Charset.....ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
    Keep-Alive.........115
    Connection.........keep-alive
    Cookie.............fc=fcVal=7625790752294348480
    Cache-Control......max-age=0
```

I have tried modifying the http-headers in all sorts of ways, adding max-age, last-modified and others with no success. Is there something I am missing or misunderstanding?

---

### Solution & Final Code

The main missing piece of code was that I needed to send the `Last-Modified` header prior to the include(). This needs to be done within the PHP file itself! I previously tried adding `Last-Modified` using an .htaccess `Header set` instruction, and although that does add the appropriate header, it did not trigger caching.
Here is my final code for **main.css** with far-future `Expires` headers and `Cache-Control` for good measure.

```
<?php
$last_modified = date("D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T", filemtime("main-shared.css"));
$expiration = date("D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T", strtotime('+1 year'));

header("Cache-Control: public, no-transform");
header("Expires: $expiration");
header("Last-Modified: $last_modified");

include("main-shared.css");
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What headers Apache would send for `main-real.css` is irrelevant, because you are `include()` ing that file through the file system.

You need to send the same headers through your PHP script before you include the other file.

```
header("Cache-Control: ........ ");
header("Expires: ....... ");
....
include("main-real.css");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added `header("Cache-Control: public, no-transform"); header("Expires: Fri, 21 Dec 2015 01:01:01 GMT"); ` however still returned a 200 OK status code. Another difference I'm seeing between the regular CSS file and the one parsed by PHP, is no `If-Modified-Since` & `If-None-Match` REQUEST Headers are sent. Why could that be and is it necessary for caching?

Comment: @filip send `Last-modified` along also. The if-**** headers should be somewhere: Do a `phpinfo()` and search for them

Comment: Wow as soon as I added the `Last-Modified` header, generated using the `filemtime()` @mattbasta showed me, it worked perfectly! Also `If-Modified-Since` now shows up in Request Headers. I tried adding `Last-Modified` before via .htaccess, which apparently doesn't work in this case. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the inbound HTTP headers and determine if the CSS file has legitimately been changed in that time. That means that you're going to be looking at `If-Modified-Since` in the request headers. Here's some code that'll do it for you:

```
$last_modified = filemtime("main-real.css");
if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE"])) {
    $expected_modified = strtotime(preg_replace('/;.*$/','',$_SERVER["HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE"]));
    if($last_modified <= $expected_modified) {
        header("HTTP/1.0 304 Not Modified");
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, except that the `If-Modified-Since` Request Headers appear not to be sent! ( I added the Request Headers i'm seeing in Firefox to my post)

Comment: Thanks for your answer however the missing piece was i needed to send `Last-Modified` prior to the include, THEN the `If-Modified-Since` headers properly show up and I get a natural 304 Not Modified. I did make use of filemtime() from your code, which I totally forgot about. Thank you.